# Matrix Rank calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I have a matrix A . A can be written as A=B+D. I know rank of B. It is 3. Is it possible for A to have ranks $<3$ . If so please prove.

Comment: Don't delete your question immediately after it's answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, take $D=-B$ or for example 
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad D =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \implies A =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and rank$(A)=1$